# Hibernate - Data truncation: Data too long for column - object field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've got a problem and I couldn't find any solution online.
So... I am using Hibernate in my Spring application. I'm inserting the Timetable object into my database. It has a Movie object as one of its fields. The error says:

Data truncation: Data too long for column 'movie' at row 1
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert: [com.model.Timetable]

I have no idea why I get the error because I didn't define anything like "length" of the movie object. Is there maximum size of the object or something like that?

I won't show the whole code of every class because it's rather huge, only the most important parts(classes have the constructors,getters and setters):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "timetable")
public class Timetable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ElementCollection
    @JoinColumn(name = "timetable_id")
    private List<Date> timetable;

    @Column(name = "movie")
    private Movie movie;

    @Column(name = "dubbing")
    private boolean dubbing;
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
public class Movie implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "filmwebID", unique = true, nullable = true, length = 10)
    private int filmwebID = 0;

    @Column(name = "imdbId", unique = true, nullable = true, length = 10)
    private String IMDBID = null;

    @Column(name = "title", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String title = null;

    @Column(name = "polishTitle", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String polishTitle = null;

    @Column(name = "year", unique = false, nullable = true)
    private Integer year = null;

    @Column(name = "coverUrl", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 120)
    private URL coverUrl = null;

    @Column(name = "filmwebUrl", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 120)
    private String filmwebUrl = null;

    @Column(name = "imdbUrl", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 120)
    private String IMDBUrl = null;

@Column(name = "englishDescription", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 500)
    private String englishDescription = null;
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>

        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3036/test
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root
        </property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="info.talacha.filmweb.models.Movie" />
        <mapping class="info.talacha.filmweb.models.Person" />
        <mapping class="com.model.Cinema" />
        <mapping class="com.model.Timetable" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map `movie` field with `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne` annotation. This field is another `@Entity` - not simple type.

For example:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "movie")
private Movie movie;
```

This will create `movie` column as **foreign key** to `movies` table.

Some useful links:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/
https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-manytoone-unidirectional-tutorial/
http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-one-using-annotations-1.html

Answer (score 2):

If no **mapping annotation** from below is defined, `JPA` assumes that `ClassDetails` object will be saved (along with its all nested graph) to DB and hence it creates a `LOB` type

```
OneToOne
ManyToOne
OneToMany
ManyToMany
```

Also, if `@JoinColumn`, is not used, again  `JPA` assumes that `ClassDetails` object will be saved (along with its all nested graph) to DB and hence it creates a `LOB` type

So declare as below and a smentiioned by @przemek

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "movie")
private Movie movie;
```